# how can we use postgresql noSQL operators using hibernate native query like ->> or?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, postgresql-9.3

I have nested JSON object like below in postgress database.

We want to run postgress **nosql operators like ->, ->>, #>, #>>** on these kind of data and trying to fetch the **"id"** parameter value from below json data list

We want to run these type of queries using hibernate native query.

```
  "FetchZotoPlatforms":[  
     {  
        "id":"PT201511180912470003",
        "platformType":"Recharge",
        "platformName":"Zoto",
        "platformAuthParams":{  
           "username":"web",
           "password":"web"
        },
        "version":"1.0"
     },
     {  
        "id":"PT201511180912470003",
        "platformType":"Recharge",
        "platformName":"Zoto",
        "platformAuthParams":{  
           "username":"web",
           "password":"web"
        },
        "version":"1.0"
     }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this link: https://devlearnings.wordpress.com/2014/03/28/using-postgres-json/

Seems to be exactly what you are looking for, found it with the first google query I tried...

Comment: That's what they do in the article:
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from candidate c where  status_counter->>'BLURR' <> ''")

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i want to use the same using hibernate native query. I am using EntityManager.createNativeQuery() and passing the sql query with those operators. Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong coz results are not as expected ,getting exception as unknown symbol.

Comment: Then maybe you could post some code of what you tried already and a stack trace?